# Laravel 5.5 Cron Job proc_open and ArgvInput problems

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

There is a problem. 
I am trying to do a cron job for the laravel project. 
In cPanel

```
php /home/mykaskco/mykask/artisan schedule:run >> /home/mykaskco/public_html/site/log/log.txt
```

when I run this command,

In ArgvInput.php line 264:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I get this error.

in stackoverflow solutions,

```
php-cli -q /home/mykaskco/mykask/artisan schedule:run >> /home/mykaskco/public_html/site/log/log.txt
```

there are suggestions like. but this is me turning this error

```
Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' custom:command >> '/home/mykaskco/mykask/public/log' 2>&1
```

In Process.php line 147:

The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

When I want the server to launch this command, the shared servers tell me that this command is closed and I have to go to the cloud server. I have no idea what I need to do. I write here because the other solutions do not work, so maybe one of you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem too and I found the solution from here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/setting-up-cron-job-in-cpanel

You just need to add

```
-d register_argc_argv=On
```

Between `php` and the path to `artisan`.

Comment: I am using Laravel & Direct admin. This solution doesn't work, too, unfortunately.